# Lambda function in Java 8 with no parameter and returning value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to convert a simple Java function to a lambda 8 function without any parameter, and then call it:

```
public int getMissing() {
  return 0;
}
```

how to convert above to java8 lambda format?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Answer (score 24):

Your case is similar with `Supplier` in Java 8

```
 Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 0;
 System.out.println(supplier.get());
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not really convert methods into lambdas directly. Lambdas are more-or-less implementations of Functional Interfaces created on the fly without the overhead of the classic anonymous inner function approach.

So, if you want to pass it around as a lambda, you need to find a matching Functional Interface and assign a lambda to it.

In this case, you have a method without parameters that returns an `int` and one of the possible choices would be to use `IntSupplier`:

```
IntSupplier supplier = () -> 0;
```

and now, you can call it by doing:

```
supplier.getAsInt()
```

---

If you want to return a boxed `Integer`, you would need to use a generic `Supplier<T>`:

```
Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 0;
supplier.get(); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you intend to do with that value, but a generator has the form `() -> Int` - something like,

```
IntStream.generate(() -> 0).limit(1).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you omit the `limit(1)` then you will get an infinite number of zeros, if you need to preserve order use `forEachOrdered` (instead of `forEach`).

Answer (score 0):

To have a lambda function you don't need to input anything or output anything back.

The entry point of the java code needs to be of certain format as described in the documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-step4-optional.html

You can use any code converter to convert java code, follow the instructions above for entry point, upload and call an external url (via api gateway) or test with the test button in aws console.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda solves issues that with anonymous classes and interfaces that hava one method. Java8 has predefined functional interfaces(Function,Predicate,Consumer) which all accept parameters. you can define custom functional interface that has no paramter.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following:

```
public interface Function<T> {
    public T apply();
}
```

With this, you can do something like

```
methodThatAcceptsFunction(() -> { getMissing(); });
```